# Code Editor for IEC61131

Tags: automation, code-editor

I am an Automation Engineer and work mostly with Beckhoff (Structured Text) and was thinking if there was any way I could create a "custom language" in any of the code editors, so that I can minimize the repeating of the syntax and reduce minor syntax errors like missing semi-colon at the end of the line.

I have seen fair few number of code editors, and quite amazingly beautiful ones, night mode editors and with great support for the widely used languages. I would love to use them but since they lack support for TWINCAT or Structured text, I feel I am missing out.

Any help or advice about even if this is possible would be great.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: This question is quite vague and it's very likely you will not get helpful answers. Perhaps try to be more specific? Have you done any research on this? Are there any specific points that trouble you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it it helps, because your question was asked in july... but i'll give it a try...

Unfortunately Beckhoff uses the Codesys IDE for editing Twincat 2.x PLC-Programs. Now with the all new Twincat 3.x, Beckhoff switched to the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 (and 2012) as IDE. There are a lot more features added to the language (IEC61131-3) for example object oriented programming. These features are all supported in the new IDE and the code editing features are a lot better than the old were...

As advice i can only give the one to change to Twincat 3.1. You can download it from the beckhoff website (www.beckhoff.com) and give it a free try for 7 days (including runtime). After that you have renew a trial serial and then you can try another 7 days and so on...